# Пытаюсь разобраться в чужом коде

Tags: php

```
function generate_xml($real_id)
{
  global $app_list_strings;
  $realty = new Realty();
  //$realty->retrieve($_REQUEST['realty_id']);
  $realty->retrieve($real_id);
  $real_id = $realty->id;
  $real_id_out = $realty->realty_id;        
  $ass_user = new User();
  $ass_user->retrieve($realty->assigned_user_id);
  // $ass_user->retrieve("1");

  $phone = $offer->appendChild($dom->createElement('phone'));
  $phone->appendChild($dom->createTextNode($ass_user->phone_work.';'.$ass_user->phone_mobile));
}
```

Так работает - выдает `phone_mobile` пользователя с `realty_id`

C `$ass_user->retrieve("1")` выдает `phone_mobile` пользователя с `id=1`

В другом файле

```
$ass_user = new User();
$user->retrieve(1);

if ($element == 'phone')
{
  $mDom = $dom_parent->appendChild($this->dom_root->createElement($element));
  $mDom->appendChild($this->dom_root->createTextNode($ass_user->phone_mobile));
```

C `$ass_user->retrieve("1")` выдает `phone_mobile` пользователя с `id=1`

Нужно сделать, что бы работало как в предыдущем файле.

Как выполнить перебор по `id`?

Comment: *Нужно сделать, что бы работало как в предыдущем файле* - ну так посмотрите как там сделано, и сделайте по-своему.

Comment: Я показал как было сделано в другом файле, соответственно посмотрел. Если бы я мог сделать по своему - не спрашивал бы. Кажется ресурс как раз для того, что бы задавать вопросы.

Answer (score 1):

Решилось просто, но не понятно..

```
$user = new User();
    //$user->retrieve(1);
    $user->retrieve($this->bean->assigned_user_id);
    //print_r($this->bean->assigned_user_id);



    if ($element == 'phone')
    {
        if ($user->phone_mobile!='')
        {

            $mDom = $dom_parent->appendChild($this->dom_root->createElement($element));
            $mDom->appendChild($this->dom_root->createTextNode($user->phone_mobile));
            }
```

Comment: тут вроде бы обрывок кода, судя по скобкам. Можете выложить целиком, или хотя бы такой кусок, чтобы скомпилировался? Кстати, спасибо, что ответили на свой вопрос.

Comment: retrieve - это инициализация объекта по его ID. тоесть если ты хочешь получить все данные по тому или иному объекту зная только его ID, то ты создаешь экземпляр класса этого объекта и вызываешь функцию retrieve с известным тебе ID. после этого у этого экземпляра класса становятся заполненными все свойства, присущие этому экзепляру (название, даты, значения полей и так далее). http://spravkacrm.ru/